# How to print information of user that is printing

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I am creating a sheet on Google Sheets and I will share it with some people. The users online can see its contents, but, to maintain the data update information when someone prints that, I would like to add to the sheet the following info:

1. The date and time the sheet was printed;
2. The user that printed the document.

The first point is so easy: put on a cell the formula `=concatenate(Today(); "-"; Now())`).

But, for the second point, is it possible to obtain user information and put it on a cell?

<sub>I saw all formulas on help and didn't see anything about it.</sub>

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Apps scripts but it may be possible using one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866787/google-sheet-add-on-get-user-email

Comment: @MC10 Viele danke, aber... I'm not familiar too, but I tested it and it did not work directly - on sheet, it informs that there is an error about user access rights, but running the script on the script editor it launches a pop-up to inform that some privileges are required and ask user to accept. I think if this pop-up were launched from sheet, it would works, but how to?